# How to combine grouping to achieve individual grouping AND combined (summed) counts when group is greater than a number

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum, pandas-groupby

I have grouped a dataframe by count. It gives me a group by each value in the column I sepcified.

```
orig_df.groupby(['count_category'])['number_available'].count().reset_index()
```

To get example of my current output, use this table:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'count_category': ['1','2','3','4','5'],'number_available': ['600','200','100','50','25'],})
```

| count_category | number_available |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 600 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 100 |
| 4 | 50 |
| 5 | 25 |

What I want is to combine(sum) groups 4 and 5 to get an output like this:

| count_category | number_available |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 600 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 100 |
| 4+ | 75 |

Answer (score 0):

If I change all of the values that >=4 in the category, before I group, it will give me what I'm looking for. The only thing is that the label is 4 vs 4+, but this is what I was looking for.

```
orig_df.loc[orig_df['count_category'] >= 4] = 4
orig_df.groupby(['count_category'])['number_available'].count().reset_index()
```

| count_category | number_available |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 600 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 100 |
| 4 | 75 |